# How to get a list of urls used by a javascript site when loading a page

Tags: python

I want to collect all urls that were used when loading javascript content on a site.

Suppose we have this [url](http://www.goal.com/en/match/atalanta-vs-palermo/2120516/stats?ICID=MP_MS_4).

Now when you right click and `Investige with Fixebug` then chose `Javascript` tab you get to see the list I am after. Here is how it looks:

[image]

Do you know how to get this list of urls programmatically ?

Answer (score 0):

try this which looks for script elements with `src` attribute and gets the urls into an array

`[].slice.call( document.querySelectorAll('script[src]')).map(function(a){return a.src});`

Comment: Is it codable in python too?

Comment: yes. check out [BeautifulSoup](http://blog.miguelgrinberg.com/post/easy-web-scraping-with-python)

Comment: Page source does not hold those urls at the time of viewing. They are post request urls.